# How to send "Is Typing" notifications until response task completed?

Tags: botframework

How to send Is Typing notification from bot application until bot process another response. I can see currently it is limited to 3 seconds, but I want to extend it until the next response come back from Bot.

Can anyone help me with this? I have seen a couple of approaches where they recommend showing recursively until your task finish its execution but not sure how to Implement this.

Comment: could you add sample what you have tried so far?

Comment: Which channel are you talking about? Webchat?

Comment: What programming language are you developing with? Can you share your code? What did you try? What worked? What didn't work?

Comment: I am using directline webchat using c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not a feature of bot framework.  You cannot control the length of time of which the typing indicator is displayed for.  Your best bet is to try to resend the typing indicator as many times as needed until you long-running task is completed. This will be a custom solution that there may already be examples of out there.

Comment: There is a workaround for the Webchat channel, where you can set the timer of Typing to 15 seconds (bot timeout value), but the OP isn't clear about the channel (s)he is using

Comment: Do you have an example of that?  I haven't heard of this.

Comment: Yes I ran it for a client. But you have to rebuild the webchat as it is in the source, not a parameter (it's just a 3000 to 15000 value change). But I don't have a demo open on the web right now

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I will take a look and edit my answer if the OP tells us they are using webchat.

Comment: And the webchat is intelligent enough to stop displaying typing if you reply before 15 sec ;-)

Comment: That here by the way: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Store.ts#L616

Comment: Do we have any implementations in c#?

Comment: Just a note - if you use a timer be careful about passing in context as a parameter to the callback. I believe the context defines the callback to handle the user's input. If the user has interacted with the bot since the timer was set, the original context passed as the callback may not be correct any more and trigger the wrong callback!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the typing activity every couple seconds while your processing runs asynchronously. This uses a bit of extra bandwidth, so your call. e.g.

```
var search = searchclient.Documents.SearchAsync(query);

var typing = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
typing.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;

do {
    turnContext.SendActivityAsync(typing);
} while (!search.Wait(2000));

var results = search.Result.Results;
```

Or set the wait to 4 seconds, or a random number between 2 and 5 seconds, so it looks like the bot is typing a little, thinking, then typing more...

Answer (score -2):

Virtually all chats employ forms of faking the "real time" presence of the typing indicator. You are best to not even try, instead letting it vary randomly at the client side, and heuristically altering to your own logic, and have any end event cancel it. Especially if your API footprint is part of your operating cost.